# Can't get baseprice to output to subtotal

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

Im trying to create a calculator of sorts that adds up the base price, any radio buttons/check marks added, plus tax and puts the result in the subtotal. Why cant I get my baseprice textbox to appear in my subtotal textbox? Ive tried a couple of methods but they don't seem to work. Any advice guys? 
Heres my code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }
            private void txttradein_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTradein.Text = txtTradeIn.Text;
    }
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double BasePrice = double.Parse(txtBasePrice.Text);
        try
        {
          if (BasePrice < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
                txtBasePrice.Focus();
                txtBasePrice.SelectAll();
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            txtBasePrice.SelectAll();
            MessageBox.Show("Numbers Only");

        }
        try
        {
            double TradeIn= double.Parse(txtTradeIn.Text);
            if(TradeIn < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
                txtTradeIn.Focus();
                txtTradeIn.SelectAll();
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            txtTradeIn.SelectAll();
            MessageBox.Show("Numbers Only");

        }
        double stereoPrice = 0, leatherPrice = 0, navPrice = 0;
        if (chkStereo.Checked) {
            stereoPrice = 425.76;
        } if (chkLeather.Checked){ 
                leatherPrice = 987.41;
        } if (chkComputer.Checked){ 
                navPrice = 1741.23;
        }

        double exteriorFinish = 0;
        if(radPearlized.Checked)
        {
            exteriorFinish = 345.72;

        }
        else if (radCustom.Checked)
        {
            exteriorFinish = 599.99;
        }
        else
        {
            exteriorFinish = 0;
        }

        double subTotal = stereoPrice + leatherPrice + navPrice +   exteriorFinish;

        double txtRate = 0.08, tax = 0;
        tax = subTotal * txtRate;
        txtTax.Text = tax.ToString();
        txtSubtotal.Text = subTotal.ToString();
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: "...they don't seem to work..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: Yes I have debugged it, no errors so far. But to clarify my base price isn't outputting to my subtotal. What could be causing this?

Comment: Declare `BasePrice` outside the `try{}` block and add `BasePrice` to `subTotal`.

Comment: @void I'm sure you would have found this through debugging. Did you inspect the variables as you stepped through your code?

Answer (score 1):

Please declare the base price variable outside try block. This variable is declared inside try block , so it can't be accessed outside.

Also , you are not even using base price variable in calculation. see below -

```
    double subTotal = stereoPrice + leatherPrice + navPrice +   exteriorFinish;
```

Comment: Yeah its still not outputting to subttotal

Comment: It just defaults to zero it doesn't output my input from the baseprice.

Comment: you are not using baseprice in your formula.